# Закинул на хостинг сайт на Flask-е, ошибка 500 Internal Server

Tags: python, flask

Итак, сайт с достопримечательностями.
Есть маршрут

```
@app.route('/addpost')
def addpost():
  if request.methods == 'POST':
     if request.files:
         image = request.files['image']
         image.save(f'static/images/{image.filename}')
         session['image'] = f'static/images/{image.filename}'


return redirect(" НА КАКОЙ ТО ДРУГОЙ МАРШРУТ ")
```

Что происходит. Я просто загружаю фотку. Сохраняю ее в папке. В сессию передаю путь к фото чтобы потом, на другом маршруте сделать обработку и сохранить маршрут из сессии в бд. Если делать на локальном сервере, то есть обычный app.run из flask-а, у меня все работает. Взял бесплатный хостинг pythoneverywhere, закинул теперь весь код туда. Убрал заранее app.run() чтобы код заработал. Front полностью отображается. Перехожу на `@app.route('/addpost')`. Выбираю фото. Нажимаю загрузить. Вылетает ошибка 500 Internal Server error. Пожалуйста помогите

Comment: Читайте в логах сервера, почему вылетает ошибка 500

Comment: @andreymal. No such file or directory: 'static/images/qayrokum.jpg'. Я удалил еще строку где создается сессия. Он просто не сохраняет. Файл назван на английском, формат jpg

Comment: Тогда отсюда логичный вопрос — почему вы решили, что должно сохранять? Каталог `static/images` существует в текущем рабочем каталоге? Что вообще такое «текущий рабочий каталог» на pythonanywhere?

Comment: @andreymal. Понял. Решил проблему. Для сервера надо было указать и главный каталог mysite. Т.е mysite/static/images/